# Error in installing R package "SchedulerR"

Tags: r

I am trying to install "SchedulerR" package by `install.packages("SchedulerR")`, but its shows a message

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package
>   ‘SchedulerR’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

how to fix this ?

Comment: `scheduleR` is not on CRAN. The github repo is not a proper package, so most other methods (including `devtools::install_github`) probably won't work. I suggest you read and try the installation instructions in the [`README.md`](https://github.com/Bart6114/scheduleR/blob/master/README.md) file.

Comment: it's `scheduleR` , not `schedulerR` like in your code and error message (which shows it's not a typo here). there only one "R" at the end.

Comment: That error message almost always means you've misspelled the package name.